# how to individuate two separate sets of points within a distribution

Tags: matlab, distribution, cluster-analysis, points

I have some difficulties in distinguishing univocally two or more sets of points within a distribution on a bidimensional plane. I would like to separate those points in two different arrays on the basis of their position (they form two separate distribution). I was thinking something like using polar transformation (cart2pol), ordering them according to the angle and than using hist command to see the arrangement, but I cannot manage how to make a stable and univocal solution (because the position of those points isn't known beforehand). thanks for help.

Comment: what do you know of the generating model? can you provide an example scatter plot?

Comment: Can you clarify it a bit? If I understood correctly, you have a set of points in a bidimensional plane, and you know that every point belongs to either of two groups; you need to identify the group of each point, right? Then the only way to solve the specific problem is to have a look at the data, so, if you can, provide a scatter plot as suggested by Shai.

Comment: a = [11.5138   -3.9854;
   18.0048    6.8261;
  -14.9453   -6.7974;
   20.4042    7.7344;
  -14.7757   -0.5343;
   15.7489  -17.5441;
   14.3219   -2.7149];
plot(a(:,1), a(:,2), 'o'); % to see the wo distibution
I Would like to separate points in two groups (in this case one with positive x and the other with negative x). But as I said I don't know beforehand their coordinates (because they are obtained by an image) and a method to distinguish them univocally.